# What could the problem with mini.c:5054 vtable be?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios

I am currently developing an iPad app with MonoTouch.
After a week development I finally got my iPad back for testing but now when I try to run the app on the iPad with the new version of monotouch (4.0) I get the following error:

> - Assertion at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:5054,
>     condition `vtable' not met
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> at System.TypeLoadException..ctor
>   (string,string) <0x00023>   at
>   (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   <0xffffffff>

On the simulator runs fine. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution didn't help.
Any Ideas where I could start looking for the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: I created an empty solution from scratch that only displays a label and I have the same problem. It is definitely something to do with the new version of monotouch.

Comment: Completely reinstalled the mono framework v 2.10.1_3 and Monotouch 4.0.0 and the problem remains. Not Cool!

Comment: If I select the option to Link the SDK Libraries on the simulator I get a System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this with one other users, and it was related to either linking a thumb library, or not rebuilding the solution entirely.  If you are seeing this without this behaviour we will need you to file a bug attaching your solution and all the pertinent versions at http://monotouch.net/Support so we can work with you to determine why.

Answer (score 0):

It has been very strange. I did some more tests and found the following: my original project was called FliteLevel1, the test that I tried next with only a label was called FliteLevel2. Both didn't work. Today I decided to make another test and I called it Test4. This new test worked OK. So just to rule the possibility out I made a new test and called it FliteLevel3. This test didn't work either. The projects FliteLevel2, Test4 and FliteLevel3 all had exactly the same code but only Test4 worked. I rebuilt my project under a new name and it is working again. All very strange, and leaves you with a sense of Voodoo to the whole thing that is not cool.